# Is spargier a valid passive present infintive of spargo?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive

I noticed that [ignoro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignoro#Latin) has the passive present infinitives ignōrārī, ignōrārier. This made me wonder if other verbs has the second -er version. The wiktionary page for [spargo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spargo#Latin) does not list a second one, but I found this from [Horace](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D2v00Yj_CysC&lpg=PA378&ots=VXVCeedanO&dq=spargier%20agno&pg=PA378#v=onepage&q=spargier%20agno&f=false):

> ara castis
>   vincta verbenis avet immolato
>   spargier agno

Tell me if you think I should update the wiktionary page.

Answer (score 8):

That does indeed look like a passive infinitive:

> …ara castis / vincta verbenis avet immolato / **spargier** agno.
>   *…the altar decorated with fresh foliage wants **to be sprinkled** with [blood from] a sacrificed lamb.*

And I'm not too surprised to see it, really; the *-ier* infinitive shows up plenty of times in poetry, as well as in older prose. I'm not sure why Wiktionary chooses to specially mark the verbs where this form is attested, when it doesn't particularly care about attestation for any other inflections.

Comment: A [corpus search for words ending in -ier in Plautus](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ier%23+%5BPl%5D) returns about 100 examples, if you exclude false positives like *mulier*!

Comment: @brianpck: Great! That could be the heart of an Answer.